# Infinitude of primes in every narrow ideal classes

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. Is it true that for every narrow ideal class $\mathcal{C}$ there exists infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{C}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Apply the Chebotarev density theorem to $H/K$ where $H$
is the narrow Hilbert class field of $K$.

Comment: I see. And since $H$ is abelian over $K$ I also get that the proportion of such prime ideals is exactly one over the class number of $K$?